# iPhone: How to show UIWebview on top of UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios4

In my Universal app which supports IOS4 and later, I have a UINavigationController and pushing UITableViews using UITableViewController.

Some pages may need to show some messages in HTML so I wanna use WebView. So I imagined like this;

When a new tableview is pushed I will check if it needs to show any messages if yes the new window will open up with a webview on top of the tableview covering maybe %80 of the screen and the tableview is disabled at that moment, when user is done reading the webview they will close it and tableview will be get activated again. Also there will be a message icon on the navigation bar to re-open and re-read the messages again.

How can I do this any ideas?

Comment: Why not take the whole screen for reading? Is the remaining 20% useful to the user at that moment? Modal box for reading a webpage is a bad idea even for a desktop browser.

Comment: @vk.edward.li thats not for webpage but shwoing some html content in the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

present the webview modally when the tableview appears:

create your viewcontroller (that has a webview):

```
UIViewController *webUIViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
```

locate the navigation controller:

```
UINavigationController *myNavController = [self navigationController];
```

present your webview modally:

```
[myNavController presentModalViewController:webUIViewController animated:YES];
```

I'd probably only do this for web documents stored locally in the apps bundle though - as you want the user to get feedback of any network loading and what if they have no internet access?

Comment: tnx I tried it seems to work but; how can I make it not covering whole screen but on top of tableview and how to close when done?

Comment: I don't think the webview has to fill the viewcontroller's view - make the background color of the view transparent. Add a custom close button in the modal view to call a method in the parent viewcontroller  which dismisses the modal view.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `[[cell contantView] addSubview:aWebView]`.

For instance, you have a boolean : `iMustShowAWebView`

in cellforrowatindexpath

```
if (iMustShowAWebView) {
     [[cell contantView] addSubview:aWebView]
}
```

in heighForRowAtIndexPath

```
if (iMustShowAWebView)
     return 44;
 else 
     return 0;
```